# Improve SQL Server Query With Multiple Joins To Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I need help in improving performance of a SQL query. I have a tblThings and tblTexts. tblThings has around 10 TextIDs. The query I have left joins on these tables 10 times which is quite slow.

Here is a simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT th.ThingID, th.DescTextID, th.ColourTextID, tDesc.Text AS Desc, tCol.Text AS Colour
FROM tblThings th
LEFT JOIN tblTexts tDesc ON tDesc.TextID = th.DescTextID
LEFT JOIN tblTexts tCol ON tCol.TextID = th.ColourTextID
--and so on around 10 times
```

I would appreciate it the help.

Comment: Can I ask why there are multiple left joins and what is your `clustered INDEX` on  `tblThings` and `tblTexts`?

Comment: Well, do you have any other conditions which you are using for filtering the data except only joins ? If you have then please provide other conditions in the query sample and can you please test what's the data volume of both table ?

Comment: @LJ The multiple joins are to look up translation for globalisation for each column.

Comment: @Suraz This is the view I'm creating and depending on requirement, the view may return anything from 100 to 5000 rows. tblThings has around 500,000 rows and tblTexts around 15,000

Comment: @kyaqb can you please provide full query which you are using in the view so that we can analyze performance area in terms of indexing, use of temporary table.

Comment: I am assuming that the query is in a stored procedure. Check the performance by doing globalization checkups separated into a T-SQL function (to remove joins to functions). Let us know the performance results. In other words, change the logic of globalization checkup into a stored function and then compare the performance difference.

Comment: Please tag the sql-server version you are using

Comment: Are you saying, look up translation of TextID in a stored procedure and call that from the query instead of left joining? If so, wouldn't this mean looking up translations around 10 times for each row?

Comment: How do I change the tag?

Comment: @LJ It takes longer to pull individual pieces of translated data using a function.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the query. As you must look up text in a text table (for internationalization reasons probably), you are forced to write the query thus.

There should be an index on `tblTexts(TextID)` of course.

Comment: Do you mean a PrimaryKey index on TextID? Sorry I'm not an advanced SQL user.

Comment: If TextID uniquely identifies a record in tblTexts, then yes, make it the primary key. And SQL Server automatically creates an index on the primary key.

Comment: Then this looks fine to me and I have no idea how to improve it. Sorry.